# cout error while using functions

Tags: c++, function, c++11, visual-c++, cout

I've encountered a problem while trying to create a code which converts decimal numbers to binary, using functions. At first I created the code using only main function and it worked fine, but decided to modify it to use function. I believe code is written right, however when I try to `cout` my answer I get a big number like `115120160758866453687091316369641637416`.

This is the code

```
  #include <iostream>
    #include <math.h>

    using namespace std;
int* unsigned_dec(int dec_M) { //function for converting absolute part of          numbers

    int bin[8] = { 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 };
    int ind = 7;
    int arr_ind = 0;
    for (int base = (int)abs(dec_M); base > 0; base = base / 2) {

        if (base % 2 == 0) {

            bin[arr_ind] = 0;
            ind--;
        }
        else {
            bin[arr_ind] = 1;
            ind--;
        }
        arr_ind++;
    }
    return bin;

}


int main() {// main function
    int dec_N;
    cin >> dec_N;
    int* bin_main = unsigned_dec(dec_N); //we are not sure if we are     assigning the returned value of function to array in correct  

for (int i = 0; i <= 7; i++) {

        cout << bin_main[i];
}
cout << endl;

return 0;
}
```

then I tried to change the cout code to

```
cout << bin_main[0] << bin_main[1] << bin_main[2] << bin_main[3] << bin_main[4] << bin_main[5] << bin_main[6] << bin_main[7] << endl;
```

And this worked fine.
Then I wrote the same 2nd variant of cout in other way

```
cout << bin_main[0];
cout << bin_main[1];
cout << bin_main[2];
cout << bin_main[3];
cout << bin_main[4];
cout << bin_main[5];
cout << bin_main[6];
cout << bin_main[7];
cout << endl;
```

and my code started to `cout` the same strange number. I think that all 3 ways of `couts` are almost the same (especially 2 and 3), but don't understand what makes it not to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int bin[8] = { 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 };
```

is allocated on [stack](http://gribblelab.org/CBootcamp/7_Memory_Stack_vs_Heap.html). You should either allocate `bin` on heap

```
auto bin = std::unique_ptr<int, std::default_deleter<int[]>>(new int[8]);
```

or even better, use `std::vector`

Comment: I changed my `int bin[8] = { 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 }; `  to `int* bin = new int[8];`, which as I understood creates heap instead of stack.   Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

you are returning pointer to local array of intbin[] in `unsigned_dec`. This array on stack of function unsigned_dec will get invalidated once another function from `main` gets called i.e `cout` operator .

Answer (score 0):

As others have already mentioned: A function should never return a pointer to a local variable. Local variable is not valid when the function returns.

A better way is to use a vector and just make the function return the vector.

Something like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

//function for converting absolute part of numbers
vector<int> unsigned_dec(int dec_M) {
    vector<int> bin;   // Create a vector
    bin.resize(8, 0);  // Fill it with 8 elements initialized to zero

    int arr_ind = 0;
    // Note: added check for arr_ind being valid
    for (int base = (int)abs(dec_M); base > 0 && arr_ind < 8; base = base / 2) {
        if (base % 2 == 0) {
            bin[arr_ind] = 0;
        }
        else {
            bin[arr_ind] = 1;
        }
        arr_ind++;
    }
    return bin; // Return the vector
}


int main() {
    int dec_N;
    cin >> dec_N;
    vector<int> bin_main = unsigned_dec(dec_N);
    for (int i = 0; i < bin_main.size(); i++) {
        cout << bin_main[i];
    }
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note: returning a vector should usually not be done (anywhere that one cares about performance at least), or at least only be done very cautiously, in C++ before C++11, since the language didn't get move constructors/assignment until then.

Comment: C++11 is assumed so returning a vector is not a major problem. Anyone carrying about performance would use C++11. And btw I don't think performance was OPs main concern.

Comment: RVO will usually optimize the copy away.